# Do I really need a constructor for this tsx component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting an error preventing compilation. I can add `any` to the StoriesComponent return type, and then everything works fine. However, I've heard this isn't good practice (I'm pretty new to TS). I want to return an array of Story elements here, so I'm sure how the compilation error message is pointing me in the right direction. Any ideas? Here it is for reference: `JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key`

The linter is showing the error on the `<StoriesContainer/>` component below:

```
(app.tsx)
import { StoriesContainer } from "./containers/StoriesContainer";
export const App = () => <StoriesContainer />;
```

I think the problem is in the `<StoriesContainer />` component:

```
(StoriesContainer.tsx)
import { Story } from "../components/Story";

export const StoriesContainer = () => {
  const [storyIds, setStoryIds] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getStoryIds().then((data) => setStoryIds(data));
  }, []);
  return storyIds.map((storyId: number, index) => {
    return <Story />;
  });
};
```

Here is the `<Story/>` component, but I think it's ok:

```
import { getStory } from "../services/hnAPI";

export const Story = () => {
  useEffect(() => {}, []);
  return <p>I am a story!</p>;
};
```

Comment: Using any is discouraged because it negates the benefits of having types. In certain cases its usage is justified though.

Add `import React from 'react'` at the top of your files and see if this fixes it.

Furthermore I can recommend this resource: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you return `storyIds.map((storyId: number, index) => { return <Story />; });` from the `StoriesContainer` component it returns an array of type `JSX.Element[]`. You should be wrapping the returned value with `React.Fragment` or a `div`.

Current type definition for the component `StoriesContainer`

```
() => JSX.Element[]
```

But it should be `() => JSX.Element` unless you are again mapping over the array of `JSX.Element[]` returned from the `StoriesContainer` to render each element inside the array individually.

Solution..

```
export const StoriesContainer = () => {
  const [storyIds, setStoryIds] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getStoryIds().then((data) => setStoryIds(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <React.Fragment> // you can also wrap with a `div` or any element
      {storyIds.map((storyId: number, index) => {
        return <Story />;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer!